# Angular + Optimizely: How to navigate to a test page url without reload(using angular's router navigate)?

Tags: angular, optimizely

I am integrating Optimizely X to my Angular application. I have 2 variation of a page `/original` and `/variation1`.

There is a feature in Optimizely where you can redirect the original to variation1 if user is bucketed to variation1. But this will reload the page. Want I want is to navigate to /variation1 without reload. Is there a way to trigger Angular's Routing from outside Angular's context?

Comment: You can use the RouteReuseStrategy, probably.

Answer (score 0):

There is option when you are creating page for url changes called "When the URL changes", It may help you. 
Please see the attached image.
[image: Optimizely Page create]